# How to test a state stored aggregate that doesn't produce events

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, jpa, axon

I want to test a state stored aggregate by using AggregateTestFixture. However I get `AggregateNotFoundException: No 'given' events were configured for this aggregate, nor have any events been stored.` error.

I change the state of the aggregate in command handlers and apply no events since I don't want my domain entry table to grow unnecessarily.

Here is my external command handler for the aggregate;

```
open class AllocationCommandHandler constructor(
    private val repository: Repository<Allocation>,
) {
    @CommandHandler
    fun on(cmd: CreateAllocation) {
        this.repository.newInstance {
            Allocation(
                cmd.allocationId
            )
        }
    }

    @CommandHandler
    fun on(cmd: CompleteAllocation) {
        this.load(cmd.allocationId).invoke { it.complete() }
    }

    private fun load(allocationId: AllocationId): Aggregate<Allocation> =
        repository.load(allocationId)

}
```

Here is the aggregate;

```
@Entity
@Aggregate
@Revision("1.0")
final class Allocation constructor() {

    @AggregateIdentifier
    @Id
    lateinit var allocationId: AllocationId
        private set

    var status: AllocationStatusEnum = AllocationStatusEnum.IN_PROGRESS
        private set

    constructor(
        allocationId: AllocationId,
    ) : this() {
        this.allocationId = allocationId
        this.status = AllocationStatusEnum.IN_PROGRESS
    }

    fun complete() {
        if (this.status != AllocationStatusEnum.IN_PROGRESS) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("cannot complete if not in progress")
        }

        this.status = AllocationStatusEnum.COMPLETED

        apply(
            AllocationCompleted(
                this.allocationId
            )
        )
    }
}
```

There is no event handler for AllocationCompleted event in this aggregate, since it is listened by an other aggregate.

So here is the test code;

```
class AllocationTest {
    private lateinit var fixture: AggregateTestFixture<Allocation>

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        fixture = AggregateTestFixture(Allocation::class.java).apply {
            registerAnnotatedCommandHandler(AllocationCommandHandler(repository))
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun `create allocation`() {
        fixture.givenNoPriorActivity()
            .`when`(CreateAllocation("1")
            .expectSuccessfulHandlerExecution()
            .expectState {
                assertTrue(it.allocationId == "1")
            };
    }

    @Test
    fun `complete allocation`() {
        fixture.givenState { Allocation("1"}
            .`when`(CompleteAllocation("1"))
            .expectSuccessfulHandlerExecution()
            .expectState {
                assertTrue(it.status == AllocationStatusEnum.COMPLETED)
            };
    }
}
```

`create allocation` tests passes, I get the error on `complete allocation` test.

Answer (score 0):

The `givenNoPriorActivity` is actually not intended to be used with State-Stored aggregates. Quite recently an adjustment has been made to the `AggregateTestFixture` to support this, but that will be released with Axon 4.6.0 (the current most recent version is 4.5.1).

That however does not change the fact I find it odd the `complete allocation` test fails. Using the `givenState` and `expectState` methods is the way to go. Maybe the Kotlin/Java combination is acting up right now; have you tried doing the same with pure Java, just for certainty?

On any note, the exception you share comes from the `RecordingEventStore` inside the `AggregateTestFixture`. It should only occur if an Event Sourcing Repository is used under the hood (by the fixture) actually since that will read events. What *might* be the culprit, is the usage of the `givenNoPriorActivity`. Please try to replace that for a `givenState()` providing an empty Aggregate instance.

Comment: While registering command handler to aggregate fixture, I use getRepository() method of AggregateFixture. So here it initializes the repository as event store, before givenState method is called. I believe this is my problem, I need a way to choose InMemoryRepository instead of event sourced one before registering the command handler. Also I tried with givenState instead of givenNoPriorActivity, the result is same.

Comment: Ah alright, that sounds like the culprit. Why do you need to retrieve the repo prior to initiating the test actually? The Test Fixture typically just does this for you. 

FYI, the aforementioned resolution that will be introduced in 4.6.0 should solve this scenario you describe too.